# Tracking the change in a sequence in R

Tags: r, sequence

I asked something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58509411/response-change-analysis-in-r) but function gave some issue, I will try my best to ask it as clear as I can.

I have a sample dataset looks like this below:

```
 id <-       c(1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3, 4,4, 5,5,5,5, 6,6,6, 7, 8,8)
    item.id <-  c(1,1,2, 1,1,1 ,1,1, 1,2, 1,2,2,2, 1,1,1, 1, 1,2)
    sequence <- c(1,2,1, 1,2,3, 1,2, 1,1, 1,1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1, 1,1)
    score <-    c(0,0,0, 0,0,1, 2,0, 1,1, 1,0,1,1, 0,0,0, 1, 0,2)

    data <- data.frame("id"=id, "item.id"=item.id, "sequence"=sequence, "score"=score)
> data
    id item.id sequence score
1   1       1        1     0
2   1       1        2     0
3   1       2        1     0
4   2       1        1     0
5   2       1        2     0
6   2       1        3     1
7   3       1        1     2
8   3       1        2     0
9   4       1        1     1
10  4       2        1     1
11  5       1        1     1
12  5       2        1     0
13  5       2        2     1
14  5       2        3     1
15  6       1        1     0
16  6       1        2     0
17  6       1        3     0
18  7       1        1     1
19  8       1        1     0
20  8       2        1     2
```

`id` represents for each student, `item.id` represents the questions students take, `sequence` is the attempt number for each `item.id`, and `score` is the score for each attempt, taking 0,1, or 2. Students can change their answers.

For `item.id` within each `id`, I want to create a variable (`status`) by looking at the  last two sequences (changes):

```
a) assign "WW" for those who changed from wrong to wrong,
b) assign "WR" for those who changed from wrong to right,
c) assign "RW" for those who changed from right to wrong, and
d) assign "RR" for those who changed from right to right.
```

score change from 0 to 1 or 0 to 2 considered correct (right) change while,
score change from 1 to 0 or 2 to 0 considered incorrect (wrong) change.

If there is only one attempt for `item.id` as in `id`=`7`, then the `status` should be `"one.right"`. If the `score` was `0`, then it should be `"one.wrong"`. Meanwhile, `score` is considered `right` when it is `1` or `2`, `score` is considered wrong when it is `0`.

the desired output would be with cases:

```
 > desired
  id item.id    status
  1   1       1        WW
  2   1       2 one.wrong
  3   2       1        WR
  4   3       1        RW
  5   4       1 one.right
  6   4       2 one.right
  7   5       1 one.right
  8   5       2        RR
  9   6       1        WW
  10  7       1 one.right
  11  8       1 one.wrong
  12  8       2 one.right
```

Any opinions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(forcats)

data %>% 
  mutate(status = ifelse(score > 0, "R", "W")) %>% 
  group_by(id, item.id) %>% 
  filter(sequence == n() - 1 | sequence == n()) %>%  
  summarise(status = paste(status, collapse = "")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(status = fct_recode(status, "one.wrong" = "W", "one.right" = "R"))
```

I believe it's pretty much self-describing, but I'll break it down:

1) In the first `mutate` we create a W/R column from `score`: 0 gives 'W', everything above gives 'R'.

2) Then we group the data by `id`, `item.id` and select last two rows or just keep the row if it's only one in the group (`filter`).

3) After that we squeeze this `status` column into one string in each group (`summarize`). So the possible values are: 'W', 'R', 'WW', 'WR', 'RW', 'RR'.

4) The last thing that is left to do is to recode 'W' to 'one.wrong' and 'R' to 'one.right', using `forcats::fct_recode`.

Answer (score 1):

Similar but not as elegant as @laroslav Domin's answer:

```
library(tidyverse) 
data %>%
  group_by(id, item.id) %>%
  top_n(2, sequence) %>%
  mutate(sequence = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = sequence, 
              names_prefix = "c", 
              values_from = score) %>%
  mutate(result = case_when(
    c1 == 0 & c2 == 0 ~ "WW",
    c1 == 0 & c2 >  0 ~ "WR",
    c1 >  1 & c2 == 0 ~ "RW",
    c1 >  1 & c2 >  0 ~ "RR",
    c1 == 0 ~ "one.wrong",
    c1 >  0 ~ "one.right",
    TRUE ~ "OTHER")
  )
```

Comment: @Spring, thank for your reply. After I ran your code, I received this error. ``Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first", na.last = "keep") : argument "x" is missing, with no default``. I have bot `plyr` and `dplyr` libraries loaded. Would that cause any issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) solution that has some inspiration from @laroslavDomin:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)

data[, {
  if (.N == 1) {
    if (score == 0) {
      'one.wrong'
    } else {
      'one.right'
    }
  } else {
    paste0(ifelse(score > 0, 'R', 'W')[c(1, .N)], collapse = '')
  }
},
by = .(id, item.id)]
```